# How to store Cassandra maps in an array?

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0, spring-data-cassandra

I want to store data in following structure :-

```
"id" : 100, -- primary key
"data" : [
           {
               "imei" : 862304021502870,
               "details" : [ 
                          {
                           "start" : "2018-07-24 12:34:50",
                            "end" : "2018-07-24 12:44:34"
                          },
                          {
                           "start" : "2018-07-24 12:54:50",
                           "end" : "2018-07-24 12:56:34"
                          }
              ]
           }
 ]
```

So how do I create table schema in Cassandra for the same ?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

There are several approaches to this, depending on the requirements regarding data access/modification - for example, do you need to modify individual fields, or you update at once:

Declare the map of `imei`/`details` as [user-defined type](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.3/cql/cql_using/useCreateUDT.html) (UDT), and then declare table like this:

```
create table tbl (
   id int primary key,
   data set<frozen<details_udt>>);
```

But this is relatively hard to support in the long term, especially if you add more nested objects with different types.  Plus, you can't really update fields of the `frozen` records that you **must** to use in case of nested collections/UDTs - for this table structure you need to replace complete record inside `set`.

Another approach - just do explicit serialization/deserialization of data into/from JSON or other format, and have table structure like this:

```
create table tbl(
  id int primary key,
  data text);
```

the type of `data` field depends on what format you'll use - you can use `blob` as well to store binary data.  But in this case you'll need to update/fetch complete field.  You can simplify things if you use [Java driver's custom codecs](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/3.5/manual/custom_codecs/) that will take care for conversion between your data structure in Java & desired format.  See [example in the documentation](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/3.5/manual/custom_codecs/#implementing-and-using-custom-codecs) for conversion to/from JSON.